# Invalid Thread Access error when changing Java SWT Label

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, timer, swt

I want to run my program where the value of a label changes after the Timer goes off. But whenever the Timer runs I will keep getting the Invalid Thread access error and my label does not get updated.

```
protected void createContents() {
    <--GUI codes -->

    //Timer set to go every 10 seconds
      ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              System.out.println("Timer");

              lblState.setText("On");
          }
      };
      new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link from the SWT FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#uithread) explains the error and how to solve it: any code that modifies GUI components (in your case, setting the text of the label) needs to run on the display thread, otherwise this error will occur.

To run on the display thread, wrap the code inside a `Runnable` and call `Display.getDefault().syncExec(` with the provided `Runnable`:

```
Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // code that affects the GUI
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All access to UI objects must be done in the user interface thread. You can do this using `Display.asyncExec` (or `Display.syncExec`).

Change your line:

```
lblState.setText("On");
```

to

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> lblState.setText("On"));
```

for Java 8. For Java 7 or earlier use:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() 
   {
     lblState.setText("On");
   }
});
```

Comment: `(a)syncExec()` executes the runnable deferred and widgets may have been dispose by other code or user interation until the code is executed. Therefore you must must ensure that the widget still exists before accessing it. E.g. `if( !lblState.isDisposed() ) ...`

Comment: I tried to use Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> lblState.setText("On")); but I get and error on the (() -> part. The error is Syntax error on tokens, Expression expected instead. I am using java 8.

Comment: You must have the plugin set to use Java 8 and the JDK compliance for the project set to Java 8 to use lambda expressions.